# Does there exist a site which hosts collections of unit tests in various fields?

Tags: unit-testing, web, collections

Does there exist a site which hosts collections of unit tests in various fields?
specifically, instead of digging and extracting the packages that seem close to your subject of coding, I'd like to use it like shared code, see how it was tested. (and then also know how it should work)

So is there one like that?
doesn't matter which programming language they're written in.

Comment: What do you mean by "various fields"?

Comment: in whatever category you like.

Comment: Okay, I've found something nice:
http://www.itl.nist.gov/div897/sqg/dads/HTML
the NIST site, has some nice algorithms (from the past), explaining them briefly or giving pseudo code, or a tutorial.
I bet there are also "hidden" sites for: unit-tests of various things, image formats, network protocols ...
see ya, let's close this thread

Answer (score 1):

You can find lots of test code with [Google code search](http://codesearch.google.com). Search for "test" or the namespace/package names of popular test frameworks ("org.junit", for example)

Comment: Thanks, that is a pretty good resource.

All those algorithms that are rewritten in every language, protocols, formats, it would be nice if there was an article explaining the concept, along with pseudo code, and some unit tests to make sure you're all on the same page. 
right now, I have wikipedia, and the open source libraries on the web, where you try to understand the c code or whatever.
Wondering what other programmers do. Thanks